# How to delete multiple files and specific pattern in S3 boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Can Python delete specific multiple files in S3?

I want to delete multiple files with specific extensions.

This script removes all files.

These are the various specific files that I want to delete:

```
XXX.tar.gz
XXX.txt
```

** Current code: ** (all files deleted)

```
import boto3

accesskey = "123"
secretkey = "123"
region = "ap-northeast-1"

s3 = boto3.resource ('s3', aws_access_key_id = accesskey, aws_secret_access_key = secretkey, region_name = region)

bucket = s3.Bucket ('test')
files = [os.key for os in bucket.objects.filter (Prefix = "myfolder / test /")]
tar_files = [file to file in files if file.endswith ('tar.gz')]

#print (f'All files: {files} ')
#print (f'CSV files: {csv_files} ')

objects_to_delete = s3.meta.client.list_objects (Bucket = "test", Prefix = "myfolder / test /")

delete_keys = {'Objects': []}
delete_keys ['Objects'] = [{'Key': tar_files} for tar_files in [obj ['Key'] for obj in objects_to_delete.get ('Content', [])]]

s3.meta.client.delete_objects (Bucket = "test", Delete = delete_keys)
```

If anyone knows, please let me know.

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? Are you saying that you only want to delete specific files, but the script is currently deleting ALL files? That would be correct, since the second-last line is making a List of all objects. Is your requirement only to delete `*.tar.gz` and `*.txt` files?

Comment: **Side-note:** You should not put AWS credentials in your code files (it is bad for security!). Instead, store them in a configuration file by using the AWS CLI `aws configure` command.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Presuming that you want to delete `*.tar.gz` and `*.txt` files from the given bucket and prefix, this would work:

```py
import boto3

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')

bucket = s3_resource.Bucket('my-bucket')
objects = bucket.objects.filter(Prefix = 'myfolder/')

objects_to_delete = [{'Key': o.key} for o in objects if o.key.endswith('.tar.gz') or o.key.endswith('.txt')]

if len(objects_to_delete):
    s3_resource.meta.client.delete_objects(Bucket='my-bucket', Delete={'Objects': objects_to_delete})
```

Comment: Excuse me again and when I want to delete more than two folders ..
I need to copy a script like yours several times.
or if I don't do it like that?
added a line of objects = **bucket.objects.filter (Prefix = "myfolder2")**

Comment: `bucket = s3_resource.Bucket('my-bucket')
objects = bucket.objects.filter(Prefix ="myfolder1")
objects = bucket.objects.filter(Prefix ="myfolder2")

objects_to_delete = [{'Key': o.key} for o in objects if o.key.endswith('.tar.gz') or o.key.endswith('.txt')] `

Comment: One option would be to simply retrieve a list of _ALL_ objects, and then do the filtering within Python (using `startswith()` in addition to `endswith()`). That way, you only need one call to list objects.

Comment: Doesn't the `delete_objects ` have a limit of 1000 objects as per the docs?

Comment: @MarkA Yes, the `client` methods have a limit of 1000 objects. However, the above code is using the `resource` methods, which handle pagination automatically.

Comment: This does not work for me... I get
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (MalformedXML) when calling the DeleteObjects operation: The XML you provided was not well-formed or did not validate against our published schema

Comment: If you print the contents of `objects_to_delete` before calling `delete_objects()`, does it seem to contain correct information? It should be a list of strings.

Answer (score 1):

1. Iterate over your S3 buckets
2. For each bucket, iterate over the files
3. Delete the requested file types

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
   
   for bucket in s3.meta.client.list_buckets()['Buckets']:
       for count, obj in enumerate(s3.Bucket(bucket['Name']).objects.filter()):
           if obj.key.endswith('.tar.gz') or obj.key.endswith('.txt'):
               print("{}: deleting: {} from: {}".format(count, obj.key, bucket['Name']))
               s3.meta.client.delete_object(Bucket=bucket['Name'], Key=obj.key)
```

I used this method since, for large buckets creating the complete list and then deleting it can take some time. This way, you see the progress.

Answer (score 0):

My code:

```
import boto3

# NOTE maybe you'll have to supply additional parameters: region, access key, and access key ID
s3_client = boto3.client("s3")
s3_resource = boto3.resource("s3")
bucket_name = "XYZ-data-storage-ABC"

bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(bucket_name)
files = [item.key for item in bucket.objects.all()]

# NOTE Here if filtering by condition, selection of files for deletion
files_to_delete = [file for file in files if file.endswith("_comp.png")]

print(f"All files: {len(files)}")
total_count = len(files_to_delete)
print(f"files_to_delete: {total_count}")
print(f"{files_to_delete[0]=}")

counter = 0
for file_to_delete in files_to_delete:
    counter = counter + 1
    print(f"Deleting file {file_to_delete} - {counter} of {total_count}...")
    s3_client.delete_object(Bucket=bucket_name , Key=file_to_delete)
```